# Notifications when somebody edits a post that you've commented on

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

If person A writes a post, person B makes a comment asking for a clarification, and somebody (could be person A but could be person C) edits the post, shouldn't person B be given a note that the post was edited?

I see this pattern pretty often where someone asks for a clarification but doesn't show up after the post is edited. Some people proactively send comments that @-message those commentators but I wonder if it should be done automatically.

Comment: I quite often want to mark my interest in a question more than the current "favourite" does. Often I recheck a question several times when what I actually want is to notified if anything (other than voting) changes

Comment: If this gets implemented, I think I'll actually start commenting on the posts I downvote :-)

Comment: You may be interested in [The votes tab in the user profile should track posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186579/the-votes-tab-in-the-user-profile-should-track-posts).

Comment: +1 I found this when coming here to suggest the same thing. This would be especially useful on questions where you've left a comment on the question asking for clarification because you want to come back and answer it once the question is edited (in an ideal world the OP would leave a comment that says "edited", but of course that is rare). I was also going to suggest a "watch" feature as an alternative.

Answer (score 16):

In my preferences, favourites is for tracking questions I have a personal interest in, and I don't like putting questions that need work in that list, partly because I want it to be full of interesting and useful stuff, and partly because I don't like to give a star to a question that needs work.

---

### Proposal 1: `track this` like it's mine

Maybe this could be achieved with a "track this" button, whereby a Q or A you track puts something into your inbox, much as you would get notified if your own question/answer was edited or commented upon.

**Advantages**: may be straightforward to implement, by editing the code that notifies the poster of changes to look up a list of interested users.

**Disadvantages**: some people may fill their inbox with noise and start ignoring it or getting grumpy. You'd probably still need a list anyway so you could review and unfollow.

---

### Proposal 2: `watch` like favourites, but less fondly

Maybe this could be achieved with a "Watched" list similar to **but separate from** the favourites list, consisting of questions where you have a comment with a questionmark.

If your question is answered, you can delete the comment to stop following the question, thus clearing up the comments in the process.

The list would show a change when a new comment is added or the question is edited (some OPs answer comments in comments rather than edit the question).

There would be no star or visible sign the question/answer was being watched.

**Advantages**: Re-use of existing favourites code

**Disadvantages**: People will be confused about why there are two ways to do essentially the same thing

---

[Feel free to comment with further advantages and disadvantages, or indeed with which you think is best.]

Comment: I like Proposal 1 better. For one, the post would be less cluttered with comments (since Proposal 2 relies on leaving comment to "activate" tracking); secondly sometimes I downvote without leaving comment (because sometimes there's already an existing comment which describes what I feel). Proposal 1's method would let me track it even without leaving a comment. A possible complication but cool feature would be specifying a period of time for tracking, sort of like I'll wait for 1 week (for example) for the post to be improved, if it's improved, I'll reverse the downvote (second chance)

Comment: Proposal 1 has since been implemented as the "Follow" feature for posts, and Proposal 2 also basically exists now that the Bookmarks feature has been replaced with the Saves feature.

Answer (score -3):

The most simple and straightforward way is: *notify on the edits of the posts you commented on as well as comments*.

- This isn't going to clutter up the inbox since edits are a much rarer event than comments, and you are already being notified on comments in any case
- Just as with comments, multiple outstanding edits shall be combined into a single inbox item

[comment873222_269486](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/notify-commenters-of-question-edits#comment873222_269486) and [comment873227_269486](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/notify-commenters-of-question-edits#comment873227_269486) give rough estimated numbers:

- about `1 notification/day` for a 30k user and `0.15 notifications/day` for a 6k user.

I can't, as of this writing (2015-11), say how much this is compared to current rates because [inbox items aren't accessible via data.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269499/query-inboxes-with-data-se).

- Personally (~6.5k @ SO), I've had 506 inbox items from 2014-11-21 to 2015-11-21 which averages to `1.39/day`.

Comment: Here's the problem. Let's say there is an old question with 20 comments by different users. I edit the question (because it has spelling/grammar mistakes or contains "thanks" or whatever else justifies an edit). With your proposal 20 people would get spammed because I edited the question (not because the question has been clarified by the OP).

Comment: See [Notify commenters of question edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269486) for why this just **doesn't scale**

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not giving up _just because you think_ it doesn't scale. I'm seeing for myself if it scales or not. Currently, the figures show it's nowhere as much as you think.

Comment: <shrug> Good luck with your proposal. I have made my viewpoint clear. Whether it scales or not I'm not interested in such notifications.