# List my downvoted posts that were edited

Tags: support, stack-overflow, down-votes, data-explorer

Consider the following situation:

- I downvote a question / answer with a comment
- The answerer / asker edits the question and improves it

In that case, I think the downvote should be removed.

I know it's possible to find my downvotes by going to:

> `http://stackoverflow.com/users/1438393/?tab=votes&sort=downvote`

but that requires me going to each and every post, check if it was edited etc. I was wondering if it can be done with the [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

I've looked at the existing queries searched for a similar one but couldn't find anything except [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60501/my-votes) and [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79026/closed-and-edited-questions-by-month).

(I've seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92351/220538) answer by Jeff and this is just a personal view)

So, my question is: how can I list the posts that I downvoted that were edited later?

Comment: Voting is anonymous. So we can't find data related to voting in Data Explorer.

Comment: @hims056: Even my votes?

Comment: Yes. Because the Data Explorer is public.

Comment: All your downvotes are listed on your profile under votes. Your downvote also shows as an orange arrow - is there a time limit this shows? If no time limit then you can see it there. Also hovering the arrow confirms as the popup text says "click again to remove". This should be enough, as you've already revisited the question.

Comment: Hmm...this gives me an idea.

Comment: Can this be a considered as a new **feature-request** instead?

Comment: @AmalMurali I already have proposed one a few months ago, which contains some more functionality as well: [The votes tab in the user profile should track posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186579/the-votes-tab-in-the-user-profile-should-track-posts)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As explained *who* voted is not contained within the Data Explorer as that would involve making downvotes public.

What you're suggesting would be a nice to have for the good citizens who go back<sup>1</sup>. If you are a good citizen, and always explain how the post could be improved, you could look for posts that were edited by the OP after your comment and where there was a downvote prior to the OPs edit. You can't know *who* downvoted but you can check if one occurred.

```sql
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , max(c.creationdate) as [Last Commented]
     , max(ph.creationdate) as [Last OP Edit]
     , max(p.closeddate) as [Closed]
  from comments c
  join posts p
    on c.postid = p.id
   and c.userid <> p.owneruserid
   and p.lasteditdate > c.creationdate
  join posthistory ph
    on p.id = ph.postid
   and p.owneruserid = ph.userid
   and ph.creationdate > c.creationdate
  join votes v
    on p.id = v.postid
   and v.creationdate < ph.creationdate
 where c.userid = ##userid##
   and p.posttypeid = 1
   and ph.posthistorytypeid = 5
   and v.votetypeid = 3
 group by p.id
 order by max(ph.creationdate) desc
```

[Here's the Data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/138668/questions-you-commented-on-with-downvotes-that-were-edited-by-the-op-afterwards).

<sub>1. I probably wouldn't use it much as if I've commented I check back to see if the OP has replied but not thought to tell me about it.</sub>

Comment: Yes, sir. If there was a Citizenship tab in the help center, it should include the link to this query.