# List of downvoted posts that have changed

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, bookmarks

In [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196228/list-my-downvoted-posts-that-were-edited), it was asked how one can list the posts that one has downvoted but has since been edited. Specifically the question was asked if this can be done using the data explorer. The answer basically was/is that this can't be done, but there might be [a way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196229/194594) to do some detective work and figure it out.

[One made a suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19940/undo-an-up-down-vote-after-a-comment-is-left) that downvotes should be undoable if a comment is left by someone else.

[Here the suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135626/should-you-be-notified-if-something-you-vote-on-is-edited-why-can-you-change-yo) is made that one should be notified when a post one has voted on is edited. As [pointed out in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135644/194594), this could lead to a chaos of notifications.

I want to suggest that **ones user profile have a link somewhere to a list of all downvoted posts have been edited since the vote**. The list could possibly also contain upvoted posts. [A similar suggestion was made here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c?rq=1).

That way one can go back and possibly undo the downvote after an error has been corrected without flooding people with notifications. I am thinking of something that is similar to the list of recently deleted questions/answer. Votes are supposed to reflect how well the post is received by the community and [help future readers gauge the quality of the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1889/194594) ([also here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1908/194594)), but if the post has been edited, then I would like an easy way to review my downvotes.

[Some will say that commenting on every downvote will allow the poster to ping the downvoter using @username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52628/194594). But, many do not comment when they downvote ([a separate issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)).

I know the suggestion has been made to [add posts to the list of favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135632/194594) as a way to keep track of edits (and this is maybe a common way to review votes). I am wondering if it would be cleaner to keep the favorites for [other things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80081/194594).

Comment: When you're logged in, you can find your own downvotes: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/<user-id>/?tab=votes&sort=downvote` . You could write a script to check these links and see if they've been edited.