# Show if an post I have downvoted has been edited

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, down-votes

We all know it is impossible to keep track of which posts to review you have downvoted. The list is getting pretty long and after a day I already lost track of the post.

I had like to blatantly copy [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157699/245360) to become a new feature request:

> to have the downvotes section on one's own profile have a simple indicator when a post has been edited since the vote action

That would look like this:

> [image: downvotes area with stars next to some post titles]

Can we have this please?

Comment: Notified is not the same as listed.

Comment: Also [The votes tab in the user profile should track posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186579/154510)

Comment: That is a good post @matthew. Thanks.