# Query inboxes with Data.SE

Tags: support, data-explorer, notification-bar

I'm [researching a notification proposition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269472/174091) and would like to learn current notification rates for users to see exactly how much burden it is going to be.

But, I don't see anything like "Inbox" in the database schema.

If it's really not there (then recategorize this as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)):

Since almost all user's actions are public, and Inbox is but a reflection of them - shouldn't it be publicly accessible, too?

UPDATE:

What I specifically need is: *how many notifications, on average, a person of a certain tier is currently getting over a time period.* (more specifically, it should be tied to their number of *comments* - but, for a rough estimation, we can assume that is proportional to reputation)

It would be best to get this for a few meaningful points:

- regular user (a few thousand rep)
- elite user (a few dozen thousand rep)
- top user (100+ thousand rep)

Comment: While most of what appears in the inbox can be found publicly, there are some things that are *not* public (like mod messages, or chat replies from private rooms).

Comment: Well, I don't mind if only public items are accessible. After all, some fields in publicly-accessible tables are restricted, too (like vote owners). My research's focus is on public actions anyway.

Comment: As an easy way out, you (or someone else with access) might be able to simply provide me the info I need without disclosing the raw data. It's not like the rates are a trade secret or something.

Comment: It sounds like what you want there isn't the current rate of notifications, but the # of edits per user per day (or something along those lines). Those should be available in PostHistory.